# Windows Drive Keeps Restarting to a Previous State

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a Windows 10, version 21H1 (which was installed yesterday) 64 bit computer with a WDC WD1502FAEX-007BA0 SSD (C: Drive) that Windows is installed on. When I started it up this morning, all of my Chrome sites were signed out, and certain programs wouldn't start which are held on the C Drive. I found that if I created a folder and restarted, uninstalled programs and restarted, or deleted files from this drive and emptied the recycle bin and restarted, that the files would be back the way they were on start up. I have a second hard drive (D:) that keeps changes I make and I've been able to back up my important files there successfully. C Drive has 211 GB free and D Drive has 10.7 GB free.

I've tried several things, and none of these changes will stick around after a restart.

I've run Disk Cleanup as admin, Crystal Disk Info says the health is Good.

`dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` - (No component store corruption detected.)

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` - (The restore operation completed successfully.)

`sfc /scannow` - (Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.) Sometimes the CBS.log is 15MB, sometimes it's very small. I don't understand how to read it.

`chkdsk` -

```
Attribute list entry with type code 80 in file 1482 is corrupt.
Attribute list entry with type code 80 in file 1482 is corrupt.
1232640 file records processed. File verification completed.   
Phase duration (File record verification): 12.03 seconds.   
15329 large file records processed.
Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
Errors found.
CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

`chkdsk /r` - (scheduling this to be checked when restarts doesn't help, as the restart causes the system to forget everything)

During this process, I've had two BSODs, REGISTRY ERROR and SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. I installed CC Cleaner and found 950~ registry entries that needed fixing, and after a few clears with backups, got those taken care of. No effect. CC Cleaner says the three driver updates I need are for Bluetooth and two Network connection drivers. Device Manager says they're up to date when I try to update them manually.

Disk protection is on for the C Drive and not for the D Drive. I click Configure, Disable system protection (Current disk space usage is 0 bytes), then OK, it shows both as off. When I restart the computer, the setting is back to the same way it was.

Diskpart says Current Read-only State: No, Read-only: No, Boot Disk: Yes, Pagefile Disk: Yes, Hibernation File Disk: No, Crashdump Disk: Yes, Clustered Disk: No

I have no system restore points, unfortunately. I've tried resetting Windows. Cloud option fails without a helpful error message, Local option fails also. I've tried recovering with a USB drive (fails), installing Windows again with an ISO image partitioned into the USB drive (looks like it installs correctly, gets all the way through the install before needing to restart at the end, once that happens, back to square one).

Trying to update to Windows 10 21H2 gives error (0x80071A91) and updating to Windows 11 gives error (0x800b0003). Windows Update Troubleshooter can't identify the problem.

I've never run into this before and I'm not sure what to try next. I'd be fine just buying a new drive and reinstalling Windows on it, but if there's something I can do to fix this, I'd like to try.

Comment: Worth double checking Disk Protection hasn't somehow become enabled. This feature when enabled makes it so that any changes made to a disk are temporary, and when the machine is rebooted all those changes reset back to how they were when you started.

Comment: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-on-or-off-system-protection-for-hard-disk-in-windows-10.html

Comment: Looks like Disk protection is on for the C Drive and not for the D Drive. I click Configure, Disable system protection (Current disk space usage is 0 bytes), then OK, it shows both as off. When I restart the computer, the setting is back to the same way it was.

Comment: There might be a way to disable it through regedit or local group policy but I can't advise as i don't know. Sounds like a re-installation of Win10 is best. You'll be happier for it and this issue does not sound like a normal configuration to be perfectly honest. Starting from scratch will put you back in full control with all defaults restored. If it helps, the cmd command for obtaining your Win10 product key is ```wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey```

Comment: The drive ended up not being able to be wiped or diskpart cleaned or reformatted in another computer, so even though crystalmarkinfo said it was healthy, I bought a new one and I'm gonna crack the old one open to look at the insides. New SSD installed just fine and I'm installing all my old stuff again. Thanks everyone for your help!